# Which is better way to send email using multi-threading technique?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently, I am sending email using simple SmtpClient's send method(without async). It is taking approx more than 1 min to send email. So my guide told me to send email using thread. I searched all over google & SO and I come to know that there are various threading mechanism to send email. I just want to know which is more efficient and less overhead?

Various methods I came to know are

1. Using Backgroundworker
2. Using AsyncCallback
3. Creating new thread and manage manually.(I don't want to go in this direction.)
4. Using task
5. Using SendAsync
6. Using ThreadPool

I have very less knowledge about threading so pls help me. And also suggest if is there any other way to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If the library you're using supports `SendAsync`, then you should use that. Otherwise, use TPL, which is the concurrency standard as of .NET 4.0:

```
 Task.Run( () => smtpClient.Send() );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can TPL available for .NET 4.0?

Comment: Does SendAync supports parallel processing?

Comment: What's the method's full signature?

Comment: Like For a view page getting 3 types of data(using 3 SP) using thread?

Comment: By "method's signature", I meant the method's name, parameters, and return type (i.e., `Task SendAsync()`). What is it?

Comment: I don't recommend SendAsync, the main thread will still wait for it to finish sending the email.

Comment: @RWendi, only if/when you `await` the returned `Task`.